# Sorting images in accordance to CSV label in python

Tags: python

I have an folder with 5000 randomly assorted images. This folder is called "images". I also have a csv file with 2 columns and 5001 rows (the first row is the column labels). My goal is to separate the images in accordance with this label such that the images can be used for a machine learning project.

| Image ID | Image Label |
| --- | --- |
| 00001.png | 0 |
| 00002.png | 1 |

0 corresponds to not having the disease and 1 corresponds to having the disease names "cardiomegaly". This codes works to separate the data into training, testing and validation folders.

```
import os
import random
import shutil

seed = 1
random.seed(seed)
directory = "pythonProject3/images/"
train ="data/train/"
test = "data/test/"
validation = "data/validation/"

os.makedirs(train + "cardiomegaly/")
os.makedirs(train + "none/")
os.makedirs(test + "cardiomegaly/")
os.makedirs(test + "none/")
os.makedirs(validation + "cardiomegaly/")
os.makedirs(validation + "none/")

test_examples = train_examples = validation_examples = 0

for line in open("Data_Entry_2017.csv").readlines()[1:]:
    split_line = line.split(",")
    img_file = split_line[0]
    cardiomegaly_none = split_line[1]

    random_num = random.random()

    if random_num < 0.8:
        location = train
        train_examples += 1

    elif random_num <0.9:
        location = validation
        validation_examples +=1

    else:
        location = test
        test_examples +=1

        if int(float(cardiomegaly_none)) == 0:
            shutil.copy(
                "images/" + img_file,
                location + "none/" + img_file,
            )

        elif int(float(cardiomegaly_none)) == 1:
            shutil.copy(
                "images/" + img_file,
                location + "cardiomegaly/" + img_file,
            )


print(f"Number of training example {train_examples}")
print(f"Number of test example {test_examples}")
print(f"Number of validation example {validation_examples}")
```

I am getting an error in line 40:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File 
     "C:\Users\61406\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharmCE2020.3\scratches\scratch_4.py", line 40, in <module>
        if int(float(cardiomegaly_none)) == 0:
    ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Mass\n'
```

Comment: pls post the complete error. seems like its cant cast the value, next would be debug it or put a print of that value so you know the problem.

Comment: Like simpleApp mentioned, please edit your question with the full error traceback. Right now, my best guess is that you've got at least one line in your CSV file that contains two adjacent commas. When you split that line on commas, you get a list of more than two strings, where the second string will be an empty string, which you then assign to `cardiomegaly_none`. You then try to convert an empty string to a float, which fails. That's my theory right now.

Comment: I have updated the question with the complete error. Thank you for your help.